How to install a custom rom on a samsung j1 device?
i have a samsung device which was made before 2016. i want to install custom rom on it. the model is SM-j100f. how to proceed?

The most problematic part will be finding a custom ROM for you device model. Usually devices custom ROM development decreases over time. After more than 5 years it usually stops as people are moving to new devices. And old custom ROMs download URLS become invalid over time. Finding a custom ROM for a 8 year old device will get very complicated, especially considering that your phone is very limited: 512MB RAM and 4GB flash. With 512GB RAM the device was already at it's limit with Android 4.4.
